# Process further unless after two asyctask in thread pool finishes their execution

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am running two async task in parallel using `asynctask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);`.

Lets take task1 and task2 are running in parallel, now task3 shall be called to run only when task1 and task2 finishes exception. Is it possible to know when both the tasks task1 and task2 have finished their work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can accomplish this by using the states of the AsyncTasks to track when the two tasks are done and if we should start the third task in either of the callbacks of the AsyncTasks. I tested it and it works, printing out the logs in the correct order. see the following code.

```
private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task1 = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d("Test", "Thread 1");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (task2 != null && task2.getStatus() == Status.FINISHED) {
            task3.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }
    }
};

private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task2 = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Test the correct asynchronous behavior by sleeping thread 2
        //  try {
        //      Thread.sleep(100);
        //  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //      e.printStackTrace();
        //  }
        Log.d("Test", "Thread 2");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (task1 != null && task1.getStatus() == Status.FINISHED) {
            task3.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }
    }
};

private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task3 = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d("Test", "Thread 3");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
};

public void randomMethod(){
    task1.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    task2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
```

I tested this and the Logs will print in the correct order:

```
Test : Thread 1
Test : Thread 2
Test : Thread 3
```

This approach will likely not work in all circumstances, particularly if you need to pass parameters from the onPostExecute callbacks of BOTH **task1** and **task2** to **task3**. But, this generalized solution will work for simple one-off tasks that are not reliant on data from each other but need to execute in a particular order. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You @anthonycr but what if both finishes at the same instance and fails to call task3 ?

Comment: @GeetGobindSingh since the `onPostExecute` method runs on the UI thread, it will block the execution of the other onPostExecute until it is finish, which will guarantee that the only one if clause will be called at a time and at least one time it is called, thread3 will be called.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes. When an asyncTask finishes its work, it calls onPostExecute. So you can have two booleans

```
boolean taskOneDone=false;
boolean taskTwoDone=false;

//inside taskOne
@Override onPostExecute(Object obj){
   ...
   taskOneDone=true;
}

//inside taskTwo
@Override onPostExecute(Object obj){
   ...
   taskTwoDone=true;
}
```

then before you start taskThree you should check

```
if(taskOneDone && taskTwoDone) executeTaskThree();
```